# sticky div in sidebar

Tags: css

I have 2 divs in the sidebar and the second one (with class "bottom") should be sticky to the bottom of the div, how can I do that? This is the code:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="top">topcontent</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottomcontent</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your css? It would make it easier for others to define the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.sidebar{position:relative;}
.sidebar .bottom{position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same a @Chimoo but realize that you'll need to add bottom padding or margin so that the .top doesn't overlap the .bottom on small displays.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `position:relative` to the `sidebar` div, then apply `position:absolute` to the `bottom` div, you can use position properties on the `bottom` div, and it will adjust relative to `sidebar`.

```
.sidebar {
    position:relative;
}

.bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```